# Dropdown menu display under my page content

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I have a dropdown menu using boostrap card that look like this : 
[image]

I set z-index property to 1000 for the card div, position absolute. This card is in a horizontal menu at the top of my page with a position fixed. My body have a relative position and my div with the content of my page have a relative position too.

This is the render of my page : 
[image]

And there is my HTML code :

```html
<body>
        <div id="body">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1">
                        <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 offset-lg-2" id="spanSearch">
                        <h4><span class="badge indigo hide">{# block badge_research %}{% endblock #}</span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 offset-2 col-sm-2 offset-sm-3 col-md-2 offset-md-3 col-lg-2 offset-lg-3">
                        <div class="search d-inline pull-right">
                            <a href="#" onclick="showAndHide()" id='icon' ><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <form class="form-inline waves-effect waves-light" id="form">
                                <input class="form-control tags" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" onkeydown="keyDown()">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    !-->
                    <div class="col-7 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 offset-lg-5">
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right downMenu inline">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown btn-group">
                                <a class="nav-link" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %} <img src="{{ asset('/Image/contact.png') }}" class="img-circle" width="50" height="50"> {% else %} {{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.account'|trans }} {% endif %}</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu top dropdown" no-escape aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-block">
                                            <div class="container-fuild">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-3">
                                                        <img src="{{ asset('/Image/contact.png') }}" class="img-circle" width="200" height="112">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-9">
                                                        {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
                                                            <a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}" class="dropdown-item">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.myaccount'|trans }}</a>
                                                            <a href="{{ path('fos_user_change_password') }}" class="dropdown-item">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.changepassword'|trans }}</a>
                                                            {% if is_granted('ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN') %}
                                                                <a href="{{ path('front_index', {'account': '_exit'}) }}" class="dropdown-item">{{'acreat.mailing.admin.impersonalisation'|trans}}</a>
                                                            {% endif %}
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                    <div class="card-footer text-center">
                                                        <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}" class="btn btn-block acreatRed dropdown-item">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.logout'|trans }}</a>
                                                        {% else %}
                                                        <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}" class="btn btn-block acreatRed dropdown-item">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.login'|trans }}</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                {% endif %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="search d-inline inline pull-right">
                            <a href="#" onclick="showAndHide()" id='icon' ><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <form class="form-inline waves-effect waves-light" id="form">
                                <input class="form-control tags inline" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" onkeydown="keyDown()">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inline pull-right spanSearch">
                            <h5>{% block badge_research %}{% endblock %}</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
                {% block navbar %}
                    <div class="sidebar blue-grey darken-4 no-escape" id="navbar">
                        <div class="user-box no-escape">
                            <a class="logo no-escape" href="/" title="Retour à l'accueil">
                                <img src ="https://www.acreat.com/sites/acreat.com/themes/acreat/images/logo.png" class="img-fluid text-center no-escape"></img>
                            </a>
                            <h5 class="text-center">{{ 'acreat.mailing.title.website'|trans }}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group panel no-escape" aria-expanded="true">
                            <a href="/" class="list-group-item no-escape" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-dashboard margin-right"></i> <span>{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.dashboard'|trans }}</span> </a>
                            <a href="#menu0" class="list-group-item no-escape arrowContainer" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-tasks margin-right"></i><span>{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.inbox'|trans }}<i class="fa fa-angle-down" id="wrapperArrow"></i></span></a>
                            <div class="collapse show no-escape" id="menu0">
                                <a href="/message/template/{{app.user.id}}" class="list-group-item no-escape" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="true">
                                    <span>{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.addmessage'|trans }}</span>
                                </a>
                                {%- set numberNotSent = doctrine.createQueryBuilder().select('COUNT(u.id)').from('CoreBundle:Message', 'u').where("u.status !='COMPLETED'")
                                .andWhere("u.account = " ~ app.user.id).andWhere("u.status !='SUBMITTED'").getQuery().getResult() -%}
                                <a href="/message/viewNotSent" class="list-group-item no-escape" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="true">
                                    <span>{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.messagenotsent'|trans }}
                                        <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill align-right">{{ numberNotSent[0][1] }}</span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                {%- set numberSent = doctrine.createQueryBuilder().select('COUNT(u.id)').from('CoreBundle:Message', 'u').where("u.status ='COMPLETED'")
                                .andWhere("u.account = " ~ app.user.id).getQuery().getResult() -%}
                                <a href="/message/viewSent" class="list-group-item no-escape" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="true">
                                    <span>{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.messagesent'|trans }}
                                         <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill align-right">{{ numberSent[0][1] }}</span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="/message/viewDraft" class="list-group-item no-escape" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="true">
                                    <span>{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.draft'|trans }}</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <a href="/mailinglist/view" class="list-group-item no-escape" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-list margin-right"></i> <span>{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.mailinglist'|trans }}</span> </a>
                            <a href="/member/view" class="list-group-item no-escape" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false" ><i class="fa fa-users margin-right"></i> <span>{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.member'|trans }}</span></a>
                            {%- if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') -%}
                                <div id="adminBottom" class="no-escape">
                                    <a href="#menu4" class="list-group-item no-escape bottom arrowContainer2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-envelope margin-right"></i> <span >{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.administration'|trans }}<i class="fa fa-angle-down" id="wrapperArrow2"></i></span></a>
                                    <div class="collapse show no-escape" id="menu4">
                                        <a href="/admin/mailinglist" class="list-group-item no-escape" data-parent="#menu4">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.administrationlist'|trans }}</a>
                                        <a href="/admin/account/view" class="list-group-item no-escape" data-parent="#menu4">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.administrationaccount'|trans }}</a>
                                        <a href="/admin/message" class="list-group-item no-escape" data-parent="#menu4">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.administrationnewsletter'|trans }}</a>
                                        <a href="/admin/parameters" class="list-group-item no-escape" data-parent="#menu4">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.administrationparameters'|trans }}</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            {%- endif -%}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endblock navbar %}
            {%- endif -%}
            <div id="content">
                {% block body %}
                        {%- if app.user == false -%}
                            <main class="col-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                        {%- else -%}
                            <main class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 ">
                        {%- endif -%}
                            {% block flashmessage %}
                                {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('notice') %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                        {{ flashMessage }}
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('fail') %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                        {{ flashMessage }}
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('success') %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                        {{ flashMessage }}
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endblock flashmessage %}
                            {% block main %}
                                {%- block breadcrumb -%}{%- endblock -%}
                                <section></section>
                                {%- block confirmation -%}{%- endblock -%}
                            {% endblock main %}
                            {% block fos_user_content %}
                            {% endblock fos_user_content%}
                        </main>
                {% endblock body %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You should give some code here or at least the link so we can see how can we fix that

Comment: Can't give a link because it's in local actually, but i can edit my question to give you my HTML code of course !

Comment: If you have any code you should post it here to help us see what you're trying. You may also want to look at the tabs in your 2nd Picture

Comment: Create a code fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link

Comment: Code or link please, otherwise we cannot help. At least for that section..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should set z-index for fixed parent element, not for card

Comment: Thanks mate... that was as simple as that... I didn't think about that because i thought that my horizontal menu will be hover my vertical sidebar but I just have to set the z-index property of my sidebar to x+1 and my z-index for the horizontal menu to x ... Thanks a lot !